# Typescript Release Mode and Debug Mode Configuration

Tags: asp.net, typescript, webpack

I'm using `Typescript` such that there are many differences in `Release Mode` and `Debug Mode`.in the `Debug Mode` i use `http://localhost:port/` basic `URL`. *However*, in `Release Mode` I have to use `https://www.example.com/`

### Main problem

it makes me change `URL`s in `Release Mode` and `Debug Mode` Repeatedly. *Indeed*, There are other parameters that I have to change in `Release Mode` and `Debug Mode` manually which *may Cause errors to misconfiguring*.

**What I am looking for**

avoiding manually configuration in `Release Mode` and `Debug Mode`

**Clues and assumptions**

there may be a way using `Macros` in `Typescript` likewise something that we would use in `MsBuild` or `WebConfig` like `$(ConfigurationName)` And `$(ProjectDir)`

**Best desired solution that I'm looking for**

Easiest Solution in which doesn't need to learn Extra and doesn't change project Architecture.**IF** I have to use `webpack`, please put complete details around it.

**Project framework**

`Asp.net .Net Framework` or `Asp.Net Core`

**Minimal reproduce able code**

Consider you ONLY want to change this URL

```
const URL = http://localhost:port/
```

To

```
const URL = https://www.example.com/
```

in the `Release Mode`

**Possible hard solutions**

as *@Kaca992* suggested [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) can resolve the issue by using

`mode: 'development'` and `mode: 'production'` like:

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development'
};
```

[production and development mode extra information](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/)

But the above solution has these Cons:

- Takes time to learn `webpack`
- Needs to be familiar with the basics concepts of [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/products/teams?utm_source=adwords&utm_medium=ppc&utm_campaign=npmTeams2019Q2&utm_content=site&gclid=CjwKCAiA66_xBRBhEiwAhrMuLfmyUNYP9_73_4wf1Zz0uSW4FSmwOogAY1FkmpHcM_SAiey0HbuasxoCbdUQAvD_BwE)
- Needs to be familiar with concepts of bundling and minification
- Needs working with modules (Import/Export)

Answer (score 2):

You would have to use a environment variable and do checks based on that. You could create a helper method like this:

```
export function isProduction() {
    return process && process.env && process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
}
```

Just be careful that most bundlers cant remove this code (it needs to be an inline check for it to be removed in compile time). If you are using something like webpack you can easily include the NODE_ENV variable using https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/ .

This is also an excelent read into the topic: https://overreacted.io/how-does-the-development-mode-work/

Also a good way of dealing with this if you have alot of different setups would be to group all of the different values in a helper module:

debug.config.ts
release.config.ts

and then in your code you use config.ts wich just re-exports based on your configuration:

```
import * as debug from debug.config.ts;
import * as release from release.config.ts;

const config = isProduction() ? release : debug;

export default config;
```

Comment: Instead of `return process && process.env && process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';`, you can instead just write `return process?.env?.NODE_ENV === 'production';`